Asignar dos valores distintos partiendo de la misma columna
Tengo dos columnas distintas en las que tengo que poner el nombre de un planeta. La primera es el planeta de origen, y la segunda es un planeta de destino. Pero solo tengo el ID del planeta y otra tabla donde está el ID del planeta y su nombre. Pero en las columnas no tiene q ir el ID, si no el nombre. Me estoy volviendo loco con esto, a ver si me podeis ayudar. Dejo aqui mi codigo para que lo podais ver.
Consulta 7:
De todas las rutas realizadas por las empresas "Expediciones Espaciales" y "Viajes Astrales"  mostrar aquellas cuyos planetas de origen y destino son planetas habitables. Los campos a mostrar son el nombre de la ruta, y el nombre del planeta de origen y planeta de destino.
select distinct r.nombre, 
    p.nombre(p.cod_planeta = r.cod_planeta_origen) as Origen, 
    p.nombre(p.cod_planeta = r.cod_planeta_destino) as Destino, 
    e.nombre, ph.cod_planeta
from ruta r, planeta p, planeta_habitable ph, empresa e
where r.cod_planeta_origen 
    and r.cod_planeta_destino in (ph.cod_planeta)
    and Origen = (select p2.nombre 
        from planeta p2, ruta r2 
        where r2.cod_planeta_destino = p2.cod_planeta)
    and Destino = (select p3.nombre 
        from planeta p3, ruta r3 
        where r3.cod_planeta_origen = p3.cod_planeta)
    and r.cod_empresa = e.cod_empresa
    and (e.nombre = "viajes astrales" or e.nombre = "expediciones espaciales");


Edita tu publicación y pon la estructura de las tablas
